# implement Rectified Linear unit in octave

Tags: machine-learning, octave

```
function g = relu(z)

a=z>0;
g=z.*a;

end
```

z can be a scalar, matrix or vector. So is above implementation correct or is there a better way of implementing [Rectified linear unit) ReLU in octave.

Also kindly say if the derivative is proper

```
function g = relugradient(z)

g= (z>=0);

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use

```
function r = relu (z)
  r = max (0, z);
endfunction
```

But your version should return the same. Try to benchmark both with big vectors and matrices...

The derivative is fine (`g = z > 0;` would be sufficient)

Comment: Thanks for the advice